# c# convert string to DateTime format

Tags: c#, string, datetime, date-format

I am reading a string value from DataTable which is in the format :

```
"3/29/2022 6:32:05 PM"
```

How do I convert this string in this format:

```
"03292022"
```

I tried this:

```
string format= "MMddyyyy";
string dateString =  "3/29/2022 6:32:05 PM";
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format,
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
```

Comment: How did you polulate the DataTable? From a database? Which? Doesn't this database support DataTime directly? This would be far better than a round-trip DateTime -> String -> DateTime.

Comment: @KlausGütter - DataTable is generated from an Excel file which contains values like "3/29/2022 6:32:05 PM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example

```
string input = "3/29/2022 6:32:05 PM";
string output = DateTime.Parse(input).ToString("MMddyyyy");

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

You can use DateTime.Parse method to parse the input string into a DateTime object, and then use the `ToString` method to format the DateTime object as a string with the format "MMddyyyy".

More details can be found here

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring#remarks

Answer (score 1):

You must first parse the date from the original format:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out dateValue))
```

The "Exact" in `ParseExact()` isn't just for show: the format string here must be **perfect**, including single vs double letters for date parts like month, as well as upper-case vs lower-case for date parts like hour. In spite of this, it's usually preferrable to provide the format for `ParseExact()` over the easier `Parse()`, which opens you up issues around inferring the cultural settings.

Then you can output the date in the desired format:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Converted '{dateString}' to {dateValue:MMddyyyy}.");
```

Remember DateTime values themselves **do not have any human-readable format**, so you have to specify the format again every time you output it or convert it back to a string. Also remember cultural/internationalization issues mean these conversions are far slower and more error-prone than you'd expect: something to avoid. The general practice is to get a value into a Date or numeric type as quickly as possible, and then keep it there as long as possible, only formatting for output when absolutely necessary.